# Specific order four strings array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting

I have a problem regarding an specific order of four string arrays. I'll describe what the Inupt values, my Output values and my desired Output values.

Strings:

```
string[] param, vol, tp, curves;
```

Input Table:

```
curves | vol | tp | param

curve1 | vo1 | t1 | val1

curve2 | vo1 | t1 | val2

curve3 | vo1 | t1 | val3

curve1 | vo1 | t2 | val4

curve2 | vo1 | t2 | val5

curve3 | vo1 | t2 | val6

curve1 | vo1 | t3 | val7

curve2 | vo1 | t3 | val8

curve3 | vo1 | t3 | val9
```

My Output:

```
vol |  t1  |  t2  | t3

vo1 | val1 |      |   

vo1 | val2 |      |  

vo1 | val3 |      |  

vo1 |      | val4 |  

vo1 |      | val5 |  

vo1 |      | val6 |  

vo1 |      |      |  val7

vo1 |      |      |  val8

vo1 |      |      |  val9
```

Using this code:

```
for (int l = 0; l < vol.Length; l++)
{
    mWSheet1.Cells[10 + l, 1] = vol[l];

    if (tp[l] == "t1")
        mWSheet1.Cells[10 + l, 2] = val[l];
    if (tp[l] == "t2")
        mWSheet1.Cells[10 + l, 3] = val[l];
    if (tp[l] == "t3")
        mWSheet1.Cells[10 + l, 4] = val[l];
}
```

My desired Output:

```
vol |  t1  |  t2  | t3

vo1 | val1 | val4 | val7   

vo1 | val2 | val5 | val8   

vo1 | val3 | val6 | val9
```

The result table must be released in mWSheet1 worksheet with the first column being the vol, the second t1, the third t2, the fourth t4. Can you help me with this? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the tp variable? and you're using array?

Comment: "tp" string array is the array of TimePoints for a certain value in the string array "param". The columns t1, t2 and t3 are the distinct values that occur in the "tp" string array.

Comment: Do you need further explanation? Hope I put my questions clear.

Comment: Can you able to put complete code. that may be help in analysis.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping track of your cell additions (see `counts` below).
I don't know your exact code so you might need to tweak it slightly, but something like.

**UPDATE:**

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>() { "vo1" };
List<int> counts = new List<int>() { 0 };
for (var item = 0; item < tp.Length; item++)
{
    var columnIndex = columns.IndexOf(tp[item]);
    if (columnIndex == -1)
    {
        columns.Add(tp[item]);
        counts.Add(0);
        columnIndex = columns.IndexOf(tp[item]);
    }

    mWSheet1.Cells[10 + counts[columnIndex], columnIndex] = val[item];

    counts[columnIndex]++;
    if (counts.Max() > counts[0])
    {
        mWSheet1.Cells[10 + counts[0], columnIndex] = vol[item];
        counts[0]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. I had used linq to achieve your output.

```
            var grouped = tp.GroupBy(o => o);
            var groupedLength = grouped.Max(o => o.Count());
            for (int l = 0; l < groupedLength; l++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[10 + l, 1] = vol[l];
                foreach (var tbItem in grouped)
                {
                    if (tbItem.Count() > l)
                    {
                        if (tbItem.Key == "t1")
                            worksheet.Cells[10 + l, 2] = tbItem.ElementAt(l);
                        if (tbItem.Key == "t2")
                            worksheet.Cells[10 + l, 3] = tbItem.ElementAt(l);
                        if (tbItem.Key == "t3")
                            worksheet.Cells[10 + l, 4] = tbItem.ElementAt(l);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'll try this code, but only one question. Where do I put the values of the string array "val"?